# How to send a pointer to a function?(This is different)

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int step_counter(char *array);

int main()
{
    char *txt = "Try...";

    printf("%d",step_counter(&txt));
    getch();
}

int step_counter(char *array)
{
   int step=0;
   while(*array==NULL)
   {
      array++;
      step++;
   }
   array-=step;
   return step;
}
```

I need to send a pointer to a function without array. How can I solve this problem? I'm tired because of trying to solve this problem for months...

Comment: printf("%d",step_counter(txt));

Comment: You might like to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Um, this doesn't look like a problem one would need months to solve. `txt` is of type `char*`, so `&txt` yields `char**`. Just do `step_counter(txt)`.

Comment: This program is printing 0 when I did yours. It is incorrect szczurcio.

Comment: What ae you trying to do from the function? What's your expected output? If you are trying to create `strlen`, change `step_counter(&txt)` to `step_counter(txt)` and the function to `int step_counter(char *array)
{
   int step=0;
   while(*array != '\0')
   {
      array++;
      step++;
   }
    return step;
}`

Comment: I'm trying to count each letter in a pointer with this function without array.

Comment: Hint: Are you sure with this `while(*array==NULL)`?

Comment: Sure it prints 0 after @szczurcio's correction - you're counting using `while (*array == NULL)` instead of `while (*array != NULL)`. Also, don't assign string literals to a `char*` - they are consts, so use `const char*` or so.

Comment: Also this statement `array-=step;` is redundant.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is what you're trying to achieve.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int step_counter(char *array);

int main()
{
   char *txt = "Try...";

   printf("%d",step_counter(txt));
   return 0;
}

int step_counter(char *array)
{
   int step=0;
   while(*array)
   {
       array++;
       step++;
   }
   return step;
}
```

**Edited**

First, `txt` is a pointer to character array, so you don't have to send `&txt` to pass its address because `txt` itself is an address. And second, in the `while` loop you can either use `while(*array)` or `while(*array != '\0')` to check character array termination. And oh! as alk pointed out, `array-=step;` is redundant.